# NoSuchElementException in selenium in headless but passes in web mode

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@_wtv_node='0']")).getText());
```

Above code is working for web mode but failing in headless

Comment: it is a single page application. so no use of wait

Comment: What is your question? ..and why there is *no use of wait*? Do you mean *ExplicitWait*?

Comment: i mean to say object is present and also is getting displayed in headless as per screenshot captured but it is failing to extract text

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.